# Como fazer Grid do Bootstrap ficar com 2 fileiras no Mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Gostaria de deixar igual o print abaixo.. não sei se tem como pois isso eu vi em um aplicativo, quero saber se e possível fazer com bootstrap. pois tentei colocando os coll-md-2 mas no mobile ele ocupa a tela toda..

> Como ficar Asim no mobile:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando as classes **col-xs-...** que significa **extra small** você consegue determinar como quer que seja renderizado os elementos na tela. Se quizesse que um elemento ocupe toda a tela na resolução xs, você aplicaria assim `col-xs-12` se quer dois elementos ocupando toda a tela seria `col-xs-6`. Lembrando que estas classes são referenciadas dentro de uma **div**. A melhor referência sobre isto será sempre na [documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid):

```css
img {
  max-width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <img src="https://d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/assets/blog_es/ideia.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <img src="https://d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/assets/blog_es/ideia.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a classe css col-xs-6 em cada coluna. Se quiser 1 colunas em aparelhos mais pequenos e 2 colunas acima dos 767px de largura, use col-xs-12 col-sm-6.
Algo do género:

```
<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"><img alt="Responsive across devices" src="assets/img/devices.png" class="img-responsive"></div><div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"><img alt="Responsive across devices" src="assets/img/devices.png" class="img-responsive"></div><div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"><img alt="Responsive across devices" src="assets/img/devices.png" class="img-responsive"></div><div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"><img alt="Responsive across devices" src="assets/img/devices.png" class="img-responsive"></div></div>
```

Comment: Teria um exemplo ?

Comment: @PedroSerpa se essa é sua resposta, transfira ela do comentário para a resposta, basta clicar em editar e adicionar o código

Comment: Já editei. Peço desculpa, fui preguiçoso :)